# UIAppearance doesn't work into the reusable collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiappearance

I have faced with the problem of using the `UIAppearance` proxy in reusable collection view cells. 
I apply an appearance (font) for the paricular label on the whole-project level, not for containers:

```
let labelTitle1 = LabelTitle1.appearance()
labelTitle1.font = Fonts.title1.font
```

It works fine everywhere, but in reusable collection view cells all modifitcations made on the proxy roll back to default values.
I don't use storyboard and register cell by class:

```
collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

Comment: try in init method of customcell class

Comment: @danypata Just like any other `UIView` subclass, `UILabel` does conform to protocol `UIAppearance`